# & in cc mail id making issue in outlook

Tags: javascript, html, outlook, mailto

I'm facing issue where I have '&' in one of the cc mail id. As the browser default behavior full mail id not coming in outlook. Below is the example.

```
let to='abc&d@example.com',cc='efg&h@example.com',subject='sample',body='mail body';
href=`mailTo:${to}?cc=${cc}&subject=${subject}&body=${body}`;
let openMail = ()=>{
    window.open(href, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Note that "id" means something very different from "ID" in English.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to encode symbols by replacing the `&` symbols with `%26`. See  [HTML URL Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) for more information.